# changing action and data-remote with jQuery on form doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Changing data-remote in form does not work, whereas changing action does.

I'm working on a form that needs to check for validity first by doing a `POST` to a backend-server. The forms action is, say, `/action1` and the `data-remote` option is set to `true`.
After a succesfull ajax call, i change the action to `/action2` and data-remote to false, in order to jump to the next page with passing the entered field values.
What i can see is that both action and data-remote are changed, but the `POST` is done to the new `/action2` as an ajax call, thus leaving me on the same page.

Apparently the data-remote option change is not working

```
$('form').bind('ajax:complete', function (evt, xhr, status) {
      setTimeout(function () {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // Submit to forms
            $("#ds-form").attr('action','/action2').attr('data-remote','false').submit();
          } else {
            window.location = '/home';
          }
        }, 1100);
    });
});
```

In the inspector window I see how the first ajax call is being done and that the call returns succesfully. The forms action is then changed along with the data-remote option.
It then `POSTs` to the new set action, but does this as an xhr call.

If I change the form to go to the second action (/action2) without the data-remote option, it jumps directly to the new page as expected.

Comment: For now, I've reversed the actions by giving the form /action2 and data-remote false. Then on the submit button click() event do a ajax call to do the verifying stuff and if this succeeds, do a form.submit(). It works, but it's still strange that changing the data-rmote option has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't much time to investigate into this further, I've left it with the workaround described above.